# Исключение в PHP (Codeigniter)

Tags: ооп, php, исключения, codeigniter

Написан стандартный класс **CI** c методом **Set**, доступным извне по URL:

```
public function Set(){
        try {
              $this->subscribelibrary->Set();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
              $e->getCode();
        }
    }
```

В нем при вызове **Set**, вызывается метод **Set** из пользовательской библиотеки **subscribelibrary**:

В ней простой метод:

```
public function Set(){
            $int = '0';
            if ($int == '0') {
                    throw new Exception(WMException::NOTAUTHED);
            }
    }
```

Стандартный класс *исключений Exception* PHP унаследован моим классом:

```
class WMException extends Exception{

           private $errorException = array();
           private $errorMessage = '';

           const SUBSCRHIMSELF     = 11;
           const NOTAUTHED         = 12;
           const EMPTYDATA         = 13;

           public static function getErrorMessage($code){
              switch($code) {
                 case self::SUBSCRHIMSELF:
                    $this->errorMessage = '1t';
                    break;

                 case self::NOTAUTHED:
                    $this->errorMessage = '2t';
                    break;

                 case self::UNEXPECTEDERROR:
                 default:
                    $this->errorMessage = '3t';
                    break;
              }

              return $this->errorException = array(
                'STATUS' => false,
                'EROR'   => $this->errorMessage
                );
           }
    }
```

Так вот, проблема в том, что срабатывает исключение:

```
catch (Exception $e) {
$code = $e->getCode();
}
```

НО, не выводит код ошибки:

```
var_dump($code); //Дает int(0)
```

Comment: потому что код ошибки передается как сообщение

Comment: Можете указать правильный вариант? Почему я не могу использовать такую конструкцию - пока не понимаю

Comment: .

    throw new Exception(WMException::NOTAUTHED);

В этом месте создается стандартный Exception, а значит, вызывается стандартный конструктор. В стандартном конструкторе первый аргумент - это сообщение, а не код; код передается вторым аргументом. Если перегрузить конструктор (с кодом в качестве первого аргумента) и создавать WMException, то все будет ок.

Дополню только что мне так и не посчастливилось пользоваться кодами ошибки (это все-таки больше из области функционального программирования и крупных приложений), детальное сообщение на мелких и средних проектах обычно работает лучше.

Comment: Спасибо - теперь ясно, сейчас проверю и отпишу сюда